# how to require login by the user in django

Tags: django, authentication

I want that the user must login to see the detail of the property [image]

```html
<a href="{% url 'detail' a.id %}" class="btn btn-primary">View Detail</a>
```

Apply restriction on this View detail button so that if the user is not logged in then user can't see the property details.

Comment: you can do it in your views by adding an if clause or a login required decorator or  in templates by {% if request.user.is_authenticated %} tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment you can use either of those things, if you are using a function based view, you can add a decorator as follows in your detail view.

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
........
```

Comment: def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
         username = request.POST['username'] 
         password = request.POST['password']

         user = auth.authenticate(username=username,password=password)
         if user is not None:
             auth.login(request,user)
             print('user logedin')
             return redirect('home')
            
         else:
             return render(request,'all/login.html',{'invalid':'invalid credentials'})
    else:
        return render(request,'all/login.html')

Comment: this is my login function , now what i do

Comment: please explain in detail

Comment: def detail(request,id):
    
        det = get_object_or_404(all,pk=id)
        prty = all.objects.get(pk=id).rel_property_set.all()
        p1 = prty[0]
        p2 = prty[1]
        p3 = prty[2]
        return render(request,'all/detail.html',{'det':det,'p1':p1,'p2':p2,'p3':p3})

Comment: On top of that function add @login_required, import it also as shown above

Comment: all is the my app

Comment: now a error is shown when i click on view detail button

Comment: Page not found (404)
Request Method:  GET
Request URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/login/?next=/1

Using the URLconf defined in property.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

    admin/
    [name='home']
    register/ [name='register']
    login/ [name='login']
    logout/ [name='logout']
    <int:id> [name='detail']
    ^media\/(?P<path>.*)$

The current path, accounts/login/, didn't match any of these.

You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page

Comment: if user is logged in then show all the property details

Comment: Have you added the code as I said? it should work as you wanted.

Comment: sir after login it is work correctly but i want redirect  login page, if user is not logged in

Comment: In your project settings add your login url. For example: LOGIN_URL = "/accounts/login/"

Comment: it is working that is why it is redirecting the user to login, check the traceback, the program is looking for accounts/login, but it cannot find the login url, so it is throwing the error. So you properly specify which is your login url in settings, it should work.